# Range of operator is dense in $L_p$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

$M_au=a\cdot u, \ u\in dom(M_a)$

$dom(M_a)=\{u\in L_p(\Omega): au\in L_p(\Omega)\}.$

I have to prove that $ran(M_a)$ is dense in $L_p$ provided that $a(x) \neq 0$ a.e.
I have never shown that something is dense in something, so I don't know how to start.
I only know that I have to find sequence from $ran(M_a)$ which is convergent to some element from $L_p$.

Thanks in advance for any tips

Comment: My hint is to first try to show it for $\Omega= \mathbb{R}$ and $a(x) = \frac{1}{\vert x \vert}$ and then generalize

Comment: Yes, my fault. I just edited the post.

Comment: @Severin Schraven I can't use your hint. I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for any $f \in L_p$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, function $$g_\varepsilon(x)= \begin{cases}
f(x),\ |a(x)| \geqslant \varepsilon\\
0,\ |a(x)| < \varepsilon
\end{cases}
$$ is in $\operatorname{ran(M_a)}$.

Comment: Let's start at the beginning. For example $v$ is the function s.t. $M_av=g_{\varepsilon}$, so $g_{\varepsilon}$ is in $ran(M_a)$? We have to show that $||f-g_{\varepsilon}||$ and it's true, because integral over the set where $|a(x)| \ge \varepsilon$ is $0$ and from arbitrary $\varepsilon$ the integral over the set where $|a(x)|< \varepsilon$ is $0$, because we integrate over the $0$ measure set. Correct?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your reasoning. We need to show two things: 1) there is some $v$ s.t. $M_a v = g_\varepsilon$; 2) $\|f - g_\varepsilon| \to 0$. The second part isn't fully trivial, as $f$ and $g_\varepsilon$ can differ on set of positive measure (although it's measure goes to $0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$).

Comment: 1) We have to show that $ \int_{\Omega}|v|^pdx< \infty$. It's true for $v=\frac{g_{\varepsilon}}{a(x)}$  $$ \int_{\Omega}|v|^pdx \le \int_{x: \ |a(x)| \ge \varepsilon} \frac{1}{\varepsilon ^p}|f|^pdx+0< \infty$$, because $f$ belongs to $L_p$  2) $$\int_{\Omega}|f-g_{\varepsilon}|^pdx=\int_{x: \ |a(x)| \ge \varepsilon}0dx+\int_{x: \ |a(x)|< \varepsilon}|f|^pdx \xrightarrow{\varepsilon \to 0} 0$$

Comment: Correct (assuming it's already known that limit of the last integral is $0$).

Comment: It's $0$, because $a(x) \neq 0$ a.e.

Comment: Here is another direction. I don't know if this is too high powered, but there is a result for a bounded linear operator $T$ (what condition on $a$ insures $M_a$ will be bounded?). That
$$\overline{R(T)} = \,^aN(T^*).$$
Here, $R$ denotes range, $N$ the nullspace, and $^aV$ the annihilator of $V$. This is the Banach space analog of the Hilbert space statement $(N(T^*))^\perp \subset \overline{R(T)}$. The task, of course, would be to show $L_p = \,^aN(M_a^*)$, that is given $v\in L_p$ for all $f\in N(M_a^*)\subset L_p^* (=L_q)$ $f(v) = 0$.

Comment: @JMcB $a$ should be ess. bounded, but I can't prove it this way. I am a newbie in this topic.